# How do I get mouse clicks to read into DefaultListModel?

Tags: java

JList or DefaultListModel displaying ArrayList of coordinates as mouse clicks points on the graph. The mouse clicks are reading into the ArrayList but will not read into DefaultListModel addElement and show on the panel.

Comment: There is no need to use an ArrayList to hold the mouse clicks. Just add the Point represented by the mouse click directly to the DefaultListModel.

Comment: Please post some code.